# I face this error when published domainservice accessed, on bizhostnet. any solution?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, publishing, domainservices

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: IIS specified authentication schemes 'Basic, Anonymous', but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[InvalidOperationException: IIS specified authentication schemes &#39;Basic, Anonymous&#39;, but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.]
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.SetBindingCredentialBasedOnHostedEnvironment(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, AuthenticationSchemes supportedSchemes) +346523
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String multipleContractsErrorMessage, String standardEndpointKind) +804
   System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening() +244
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.WebServiceHostInspector.OnOpening() +13
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) +274
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.WebServiceHostInspector.Inspect() +39
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.VerifyAuthenticationMode() +128
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.PoxBinaryEndpointFactory.CreateEndpointForAddress(ContractDescription contract, Uri address) +191
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.PoxBinaryEndpointFactory.CreateEndpoints(DomainServiceDescription description, DomainServiceHost serviceHost) +145
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2&amp; implementedContracts) +630
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +154
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +49
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +309
   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +28
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +420
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1440
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +615

[ServiceActivationException: The service &#39;/Services/hosttest2-DomainService1.svc&#39; cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: IIS specified authentication schemes &#39;Basic, Anonymous&#39;, but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +679246
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +6
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +96
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[InvalidOperationException]: IIS specified authentication schemes &#39;Basic, Anonymous&#39;, but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used.
   at System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.SetBindingCredentialBasedOnHostedEnvironment(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, AuthenticationSchemes supportedSchemes)
   at System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(ServiceHost host, IDictionary`2 implementedContracts, String multipleContractsErrorMessage, String standardEndpointKind)
   at System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.WebServiceHostInspector.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.WebServiceHostInspector.Inspect()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.VerifyAuthenticationMode()
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.PoxBinaryEndpointFactory.CreateEndpointForAddress(ContractDescription contract, Uri address)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.PoxBinaryEndpointFactory.CreateEndpoints(DomainServiceDescription description, DomainServiceHost serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
[ServiceActivationException]: The service &#39;/Services/hosttest2-DomainService1.svc&#39; cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: IIS specified authentication schemes &#39;Basic, Anonymous&#39;, but the binding only supports specification of exactly one authentication scheme. Valid authentication schemes are Digest, Negotiate, NTLM, Basic, or Anonymous. Change the IIS settings so that only a single authentication scheme is used..
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
--><!-- 
This error page might contain sensitive information because ASP.NET is configured to show verbose error messages using &lt;customErrors mode="Off"/&gt;. Consider using &lt;customErrors mode="On"/&gt; or &lt;customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/&gt; in production environments.-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your host has IIS setup for basic and Anonymous access. But your authentication scheme only allows for one. either you have to adjust your authentication scheme or you have to have your host change their scheme.

I dont know if you can have multiple authentication schemes for a domain service.